# Why clearing MOE in TIM1->BDTR in PWM mode stops triggering ADC1 IN STM32 Nulceo-64 for STM32F401?

Tags: stm32f4, stm32cubeide

In the middle of an experiment i got stuck with an issue for which i hope somebody out here might know the solution.

I am using TIMER1 in PWM mode which is supposed be to continuously running in the background. Since triggering ADC using Timer1 update event is not possible in STM32F401, I used the following settings.

**TIM1: Trigger Event Selection_Output Compare(OC1REF)
ADC1: External Trigger Conversion Source_ Timer 1 Capture Compare 1 Event**

On sensing a particular value through ADC1 i need the Main output to be disable(i don't want to disable the timer) So i cleared the MOE bit in BDTR register.

But disabling the MOE bit actually stops ADC Triggering.

What could be the possible problem for ADC not getting a proper trigger when only the main output is disable and timer is still running ?

If this is not the proper way can ,what is the proper way to turn off output alone ?